# Operation was explicitly assigned to /GPU:1 but available devices are

Tags: tensorflow, select, gpu

My system has 2 Nvidia GPUs, a GTX 750 Ti which is assigned to the OS for OS graphics and a GTX 1080Ti which is free to be used for Tensorflow. I use the call: `tensorflow::graph::SetDefaultDevice("/GPU:1", &graph);` to enable GPU1 .

I am running TF 1.10 hand compiled and configured for C++/CMake and Cuda compilation tools, release 9.1, V9.1.85. When I assign GPU 1 to execute my graph I get the following error:

> "Invalid argument: Cannot assign a device for operation 'h1_w/read':
>   Operation was explicitly assigned to /GPU:1 but available devices are
>   [ /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0,
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 ]. Make sure the device
>   specification refers to a valid device.    [[{{node h1_w/read}} =
>   IdentityT=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@h1_w"], _device="/GPU:1"]]"